# Applying css when bootstraps stacks columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to apply some css rules only for when bootstrap stacks the columns when resizing the page.

At the moment i am using media queries like this one:

```
@media (max-width: 983px) {
    .footer-links {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    .col-info {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }

    .show-link {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .show-title {
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }


}
```

The problem with this is that the width value is fixed size. On a smaller device the columns would stack with a lower width.

So I need to detect when bootstrap wraps the columns as well as when it expands them again.

Comment: Those columns get stacked _because_ Bootstrap uses media queries that apply a different formatting at certain width-based breakpoints – so unclear what you are actually asking here.

Comment: can i use bootstraps media queries in my own css?

Comment: Look at the LESS variables bootstrap uses (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) – if you switch your CSS to LESS as well, then you can make use of those variables as well. (Be aware that this might involve a little more than just changing the file extension, so please research that.)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, bootstrap 'stacks' *after* iPad portrait size:

Before iPad =

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
```

After iPad =

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
```

So, to affect the styles, add your own overrides to the second media query and make sure that the CSS is declared *after* the bootstrap css and specificity is correct.